# Обновление полей ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Использую плагин **Advanced Custom Fields**. Как заставить работать функцию `update_sub_field()`? Есть `subfields` в основном поле с селектором `main_specifications`, пытаюсь их программно обновить, то есть добавить значения,но ничего не выходит. Причем вывести их получается, а вот обновить никак.
[image: схема полей]

```
function some_field_update(){

    if( have_rows('main_specifications', 20735) ):
        while ( have_rows('main_specifications', 20735) ) : the_row();
            echo get_sub_field('colors') . '<br>';
            if (update_sub_field('colors', 'some value', 20735)){
                echo 'successful';
            }else{
                echo 'false';
            }

        endwhile;
    else :
        echo 'no rows found';
    endif;
}
add_action('init', 'some_field_update');
```

Answer (score 0):

Решить получилось только с помощью `update_post_meta`
Заметил что subfields просто имеют префикс в своем названии, то есть если например поле имеет ярлык `main_specifications` а дочернее к нему поле `colors`, то в итоге у этого вложенного поля будет идентификатор `main_specifications_color`s, в итоге написал примерно следующий код:

```
function some_field_update(){

    $my_posts = new WP_Query;

// делаем запрос
    $myposts = $my_posts->query( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 10000,
    ) );
// обрабатываем результат
    foreach( $myposts as $pst ){
        if ($pst){
            update_post_meta($pst->ID, 'main_specifications_colors', get_post_meta($pst->ID, 'colors')[0]);
            }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'some_field_update');
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]