# get_fields не видит значений полей

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Небольшая предыстория: В типе поста были кастомные поля wp, была необходимость перенести из них значения в поля **ACF**, перенес с помощью `update_post_meta` в цикле перебрав результаты `wp_query`. В итоге в админке я значения этих полей вижу, а вот `get_fields` их получить не может. Если просто захожу в пост и жму `Update`, то все сразу начинает работать корректно именно в этом посте. Я так понимаю какие то экшены отрабатывают при сохранении поста? Возможно что то типо апдейта всей мета информации поста, погуглил, ничего подобного не нашел, нашел только `wp_update_post()`. Пропустил все посты в цикле через нее, не помогло.
Пробовал так

```
function my_update_posts() {
    //$myposts = get_posts('showposts=-1');//Retrieve the posts you are targeting
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'numberposts' => -1
    );
    $myposts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($myposts as $mypost){
        $mypost->post_title = $mypost->post_title.'';
        wp_update_post( $mypost );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'my_update_posts' );
```

Так же пробовал bulk edit в списке постов, тоже не помогает, только по одному открывать каждый и жать update

Вот [тут](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/294575/how-to-force-update-all-posts-after-import) люди обсуждали примерно похожую проблему, там только с тайтлами похожая ситуация, там ее так и не решили. Указанные там способы я в принципе и сам пробовал, не помогло...

Comment: Я почти ничего не понял, то action save_post, скорее всего, должен подойти.

Comment: Если коротко, то - програмно обновлял кастомные поля, созданные при помощи Advanced Custom Fields,теперь в админке их значения видны, но функция get_fields их значений не возвращает, после того как зайдешь в редактирование поста и нажмешь Update, функция начинает работать корректно. Но я не могу вручную сидеть и нажимать Update в 8000 постов, возможно есть какое то решение.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте использовать `WP_Query` в цикле, чтобы вытянуть посты - https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query
и попробуйте сохранить в цикле через `update_post_meta($post->ID, 'acf_name', $what_to_save);`

Comment: Спасибо, а я именно так и задавал им значения(https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1154239/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-acf/1154645?noredirect=1#comment2002303_1154645), но теперь функция не может получить их значения если не нажать кнопку апдейт в редактировании поста.